# how to instpect WKWebview on chrome devtools?

Tags: ios, safari, google-chrome-devtools, wkwebview

Apple supports `isinspectable: Bool` for WKWebview above iOS 16.4:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/4111163-isinspectable

inspector on lastest Safari can detect the iOS device connected by USB port, but inspector on chrome can't detect it, how to make it connected to my iOS device ?

chrome inspector URL: chrome://inspect/#devices
[image]